# Flask render_template

Tags: html, python-2.7, flask

New to Flask and have some experience with python, when using render_template it simply does not render the template as well as not giving out any errors.
Code Here:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder= "/templates")




@app.route("/")
def index():
        #return("Index str")
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/crawler")
def crawler():
    return("WebCrawler str")
    return render_template("crawler.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
    app.debug = True
```

HTML here (pretty certain file hierarchy is correct).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url_for('static', filename='style.css')}}">
        <meta charset = "utf-8">
        <title> Index</title>
    <head>
    <body>
        <p> This webserver hosts all webapps and will showcase any unfinished applications.
            </p>

        </body>

</html>
```

[image: root virtual environment]

[image: static for css]

[image: templates folder]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default folder for the HTML files is templates. So create a folder called "templates" where your python file is located. Put any HTML files in that folder

Comment: The last screenshot shows a templates folder within the same folder that main.py is located.

Comment: Have you been trying to access the site through localhost? If so then you need to import os and have this code: `if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)`

Comment: Indeed I have, never thought of that, Ill just test that now.

Comment: Thankyou, it was this afterall, are you able to explain why this is the case?
Sorry new to web development.

Comment: I'm not a huge technical guy so I'm not sure of the exact way to describe it. But basically you need to tell the program to host the site at port 5000 on your local computer. That way when you go to http://localhost:5000, your site appears there

Answer (score 2):

By default Flask `template_folder` set to `templates`. If you wish to change it then mention folder in the root path of the application.

It't not necessary when `templates` folder but it's should be...

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder= "templates")
```

Comment: I have tried leaving it to default however this didn't work either, I could show screenshots of the filing if you need?

Comment: @Hobnob That would be nice. Please update your question with filing screenshot...

Comment: Can you put `app.debug = True` above the `app.run()` statement. It will give you better error messages...

Comment: Just sorted it out, to do with being on localhost, cheers anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```css
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder= "templates")
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('/index.html')
```

This code might work..